# Blank Populate Data to ListView from Retrofit

Tags: android, listview, retrofit2

I'm new on android, and I've been try to populate data that I get from retrofit response to Listview, but the result was blank.

This is my code to call retrofit and call the ListView adapter

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_view, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());

    int getUkmId = getArguments().getInt("viewUkmId");


    getViewReport(getUkmId);

    return view;
}

public void getViewReport(int UkmId){
    final ViewReportRequest viewReportRequest = new ViewReportRequest(UkmId);
    Call<ViewReportResponse> call = apiService.viewReport(viewReportRequest);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ViewReportResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ViewReportResponse> call, Response<ViewReportResponse> response) {
            if(response.body().getData() != null){
                final ArrayList<ViewReportResponseData> viewReportResponseData = response.body().getData();

                ListView listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.ukmView);
                UkmViewDataAdapter adapter = new UkmViewDataAdapter(viewReportResponseData, getContext());

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed Get View Report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ViewReportResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

and below is my adapter code

```
public class UkmViewDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ViewReportResponseData> viewReportResponses;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public UkmViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<ViewReportResponseData> viewReportResponseData, Context context){
    super();

    this.viewReportResponses = viewReportResponseData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_view_list, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.viewStartDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewStartDate);
        holder.viewEndDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewEndDate);
        holder.viewFund = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewFund);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.viewStartDate.setText(viewReportResponses.get(position).getStartDate());
    holder.viewEndDate.setText(viewReportResponses.get(position).getEndDate());
    holder.viewFund.setText(viewReportResponses.get(position).getAmount());

    return convertView;
}

public  class ViewHolder {

    public TextView viewStartDate;
    public TextView viewEndDate;
    public TextView viewFund;

  }
}
```

and I successfully get the response data from retrofit also, below is the okhttp3 response

```
{
"code": 1000,
"message": "Success",
"data": [
    {
        "ukm_id": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "start_date": "2018-04-02T00:00:00Z",
        "end_date": "2018-11-18T00:00:00Z",
        "amount": 4000000
    },
    {
        "ukm_id": 2,
        "id": 3,
        "start_date": "2018-04-01T00:00:00Z",
        "end_date": "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z",
        "amount": 2000000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The getCount() is returning 0 therefore getView() is never called. It should return viewReportResponses.size() to indicate the size of the list.

Comment: hi @Elletlar, thanks it's working :)

Comment: Np. Great! :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}  

 you are returning 0, instead return the count.

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
 your are returning null, instead return list position.


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
 your are returning null, instead return id .

see below code:

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewReportResponses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return viewReportResponses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public UkmViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<ViewReportResponseData> viewReportResponseData, Context context){
        super();

        this.viewReportResponses = viewReportResponseData;
        this.context = context;
    }
```